# Parsing a single link with CURL and save it in txt file

Tags: php, curl, persistence

My task is to parse just one single link from a given URL.

The problem is that every time I refresh the page I download the targeted web-site with Curl and I use a regular expression to find the link. How can I avoid downloading the targeted website again when the given link is the same?

```
$url = 'http://ruh.kz';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/5.0 ");
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 );
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$link = preg_match_all('/<h3 class="entry"><a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a><\/h3>/', $content, $matches);
$link = $matches[1][0];
$title = $matches[2][0];
```

output:

```
<a href="http://ruh.kz<?php print $link; ?>" target="_blank"><?php print $title; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to this problem would be to remember all parsed/loaded URLs in a cache. This means, whenever a URL has been processed successfully, store the URL in a session/cookie/database (what ever serves your purpose best).

On page refresh first check this cache first. If the URL is not stored in there it is good to load/parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) make a foreach first, then parse the links as you wish.

```
    require('simple_html_dom.php');
    $url = 'http://ruh.kz';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/5.0 ");
    curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 );
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $html= str_get_html($content); 
    foreach($html->find('.entry') as $element){
        preg_match_all('/<a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>/', $element, $matches);
        $link = $matches[1][0];
        $title = $matches[2][0];
        echo '<a href="http://ruh.kz'.$link,'" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a><br />';
    }
```

Comment: but that would be launched every time i refresh the page?

Comment: Yes, when you refresh page, it will catch the link simulation Mozilla browser, so you can save it as `txt,html`,or `sql data` if you do not want.